# Coverting a tree to circular doubly linked list

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 /* The node type from which both the tree and list are built */
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *small;
    struct node *large;
};
typedef struct node *Node;

static void join(Node a, Node b)
{
    a->large = b;
    b->small = a;
}

static Node append(Node a, Node b)
{
    Node aLast, bLast;

    if (a == NULL)
        return (b);
    if (b == NULL)
        return (a);

    aLast = a->small;
    bLast = b->small;

    join(aLast, b);
    join(bLast, a);

    return (a);
}
```

in this implementation, if instead of defining local variables in the append function i.e. aLast and bLast, directly join(a->small,b) and join(b->small,a) are called, the output truncates to only one element in the list.
here's the link to problem: [bst to circular](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/109/TreeListRecursion.html)

Comment: Hi, can you fix the formatting to make the code a bit easier to read? Thanks!

Comment: this code works fine if executed as it is, but as soon as use of local values aLast and bLast is deffered, it doesn't work.

Comment: the result is the first element of the list

Comment: See my answer. `join` modifies `b->small`. So you get different results in the local variable case than the case where you don't use the local variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `join` function changes the value of the `small` element in your structure. Therefore this:

```
aLast = a->small;
bLast = b->small;  // This saves the current value of `b->small`
                   // before `join(aLast, b)` changes it

join(aLast, b);    // This call to join changes the value of `b->small`
join(bLast, a);    // bLast still has the *old* value of `b->small`
```

Is not the same as this:

```
join(a->small, b); // This call to join changes the value of `b->small`
join(b->small, a); // This call uses the *new* value of `b->small`
```

Comment: couldn't understand it, can you please elaborate

Comment: aLast and bLast are pointers, how can they capture current values. as join(aLast,b) is called, bLast should point to new value of b->small

Comment: @bullseye `b` is a pointer to `small`. You set `bLast` to the value of `b->small`. Then in your first call to `join(aLast, b)` it does `b->small = a->large`. So the value of `b->small` changes here. Yes, `b` is a pointer, but what it points to changes. Then in your second call to `join`, your call `join(bLast, a)` is using the value of `b->small` before it was changed in the first call to `join` (`join(aLast, b)`). If you call `join(b->small, a)` this uses the *changed* value of `b->small` (it was changed by `join(a->small, b)`).

Comment: @bullseye I updated the code comments in my answer to try to clarify

Comment: thank you for this explanation, got confused earlier.